# How to generate coverage report with JMockit and Maven?

Tags: maven, code-coverage, surefire, jmockit

I'm trying to generate a coverage report with [JMockit](https://code.google.com/p/jmockit/) and the Maven Surefire plug-in. But nothing happens.

Here are the relevant parts of my pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.15</version>
    <configuration>
        <argLine>
            -Djmockit-coverage-outputDir=target/coverage-report
        </argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The jmockit dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.googlecode.jmockit</groupId>
  <artifactId>jmockit-coverage</artifactId>
  <version>0.999.22</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

This is pretty much the same as the example from the [JMockit docs](http://jmockit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/www/tutorial/CodeCoverage.html).

It should generate a report with mavens "test" goal, but it does not. I've tried "surefire:test" too, but nothing happens.

I'm using Java 7 and Maven 3.0.

How can I generate a JMockit coverage report with maven?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to also add the "jmockit" dependency, version 1.3 or newer (and before "junit" if that's the case).

The JMockit Coverage documentation is indeed missing this detail; should be fixed soon.

Comment: Thanks. Wouldn't it be better to add an explicit dependency to jmockit in the jmockit-coverage package?

Comment: Yes, that would make sense, except that it's also possible to get JMockit Coverage to work in a Maven build without the JMockit library, by using the "-javaagent" parameter. I will improve the docs.